# Performance varies depending on how PostgreSQL function is called

Tags: postgresql, function, performance

I'm calling a function that "RETURNS INTEGER".

I've noticed that it executes faster if I call it like this:

1. SELECT * FROM MyFunction;

The other ways to call it which are slower are like this:
2. SELECT MyFunction;
3. SELECT FROM MyFunction;

Does anybody know if there is a reason for this behavior?
I'm thinking there must be something else happening that's unrelated to how the function is called.

I executed this function many many times and used every combination regarding the order -- meaning 1 2 3, 1 3 2, 2 1 3, 2 3 1, 3 1 2, 3 2 1.  It's consistently showing superior performance when executed using method #1.

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, costs) for the different SQL statements?

Comment: There are several SQL statements within this function and then finally an INSERT.  I'd have to pull each from the function and then mask the actual object names.  Do you think the plan can be different depending on how the function is called?  Thank you Frank!!